# What arguments are there against ranked-choice voting?

Tags: voting-systems, ranked-choice-voting

In America, most elections are based on first-past-the-post voting, where whoever gets a plurality of the votes wins.  For instance if candidate A gets 40% of the vote and each of candidates B and C get 30% of the vote, then candidate A wins, even if 60% of the electorate are steadfastly opposed to candidate A.

This problem can be solved by a system called ranked-choice voting, aka instant-runoff voting, where voters rank candidates from best to worst.  Suppose there are six candidates.  Then each voter ranks the candidates from 1 to 6.  Then the voters's first-choice votes are all tallied up, and whichever candidate gets in 6th place is eliminated, and his voters are reallocated to whoever was their second choice.  Once this reallocation is done, the 5th place candidate is eliminated, and this process is repeated until only one candidate is left.  (And there are some rules on handling ties, just as there are in the first-past-the-post system.) For more information see [here](http://www.fairvote.org/rcv).

Ranked-choice voting has many advantages.  It eliminates the concern that third party candidates act as spoilers.  And if the Republican primaries had used ranked-choice voting, Trump wouldn't have won the nomination, since a majority of the electorate was against him, it's just that the anti-Trump vote was split.

But my question is, what arguments have been made against ranked-choice voting.  It seems like an obviously superior system to me.  The only downsides I can think of is that it may be too hard to understand for some voters, and there may be implementation costs.  But it's been implemented in San Francisco and several other jurisdictions, and it doesn't seem to have caused any catastrophic problems.

EDIT: My question is not about the difficulties of switching to ranked-choice voting, but about what disadvantages (if any) there are of the system itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any practical difficulties with switching to alternative voting systems in the US?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13195/are-there-any-practical-difficulties-with-switching-to-alternative-voting-system)

Comment: That's rather extreme, as that question is closed as a duplicate of [What steps need to happen for the alternative vote to be implemented?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8589/4666)  And that has nothing to do with arguments against ranked choice other than implementation details.  And yes, those exist.

Comment: Do you want to discuss ranked choice voting?  Or the specific implementation IRV/alternative vote?  Because some of the arguments against IRV do not apply to other ranked choice methods.  And of course, some do.

Comment: @Brythan I thought ranked-choice voting and instant runoff voting are synonyms; that's how the term is used here: http://www.fairvote.org/rcv

Comment: This isn't extensive enough for an answer, so I'll put it here.  The main "argument" against is that it offers options to the two-party system.  The two parties that monopolize (dualopolize?) political power basically call the shots, so they're not going undermine themselves, because that would put the citizens' interests above their own.  We know that's a non-starter.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet that's somewhat true. There are also those in the two major parties that realize what 3rd parties we do have often wreak havoc on the two party system (one could argue that happened in the presidential election). So there are actually arguments from within the two major parties to allow things like IRV. But, yes, it's likely still a minority viewpoint within the party leadership.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan FairVote uses "ranked-choice voting" to refer to "instant-runoff voting", essentially as a form of propaganda.   There are many other methods that use ranked-choice ballots, though.

Comment: Does the question only concern elections that require one winner (like presidency) or many representatives (in which case proportional representation is a good contender)?

Comment: @Communisty This is about elections that only have one winner.

Comment: https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/3057/text#toc-H8E0C137AD4A044FF9658E6745E639A21 Worth mentioning that their a bill currently introduced to establish ranked choice voting for Congressional elections. It also establishes multimember districts so its slightly off of the focus of this question.

Comment: You say that ranked voting 'solves a problem'. What is the problem that you believe it will solve?

Comment: Just a comment - after losing elections, the losing side often suggests that with a different voting method they would have won (i.e., no electoral college, or ranked-choice ballots).  The error is that, if the rules were different, strategies would differ too.  If we went to ranked-choice, both parties would presumably nominate two or more candidates instead of just one, or find some other way to strategize around the change.

Comment: @tj1000 The problem is that "candidate A wins, even if 60% of the electorate are steadfastly opposed to candidate A" in the first paragraph.  (It's a myth that IRV fixes this, though.)

Comment: Ranked voting is not proportional voting. Isn't this a good argument?

Answer (score 83):

> This problem can be solved by a system called ranked-choice voting, aka instant-runoff voting

First off, there are [multiple voting systems based on ranking your choices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_voting_system).  The system you're describing is just one example, and it's a pretty bad one, so it's frustrating that people refer to it as "ranked-choice voting", as if it's the *only* ranked system.

This system is more specifically referred to as "[Instant-Runoff Voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant-runoff_voting)".  (Though taken literally, there are [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplementary_vote) [systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingent_vote) that use instant runoff rounds, but "IRV" always means this particular system.)

Second, it has a number of problems:

### IRV has a spoiler effect

You said:

> It eliminates the concern that third party candidates act as spoilers.

It doesn't, though.  It [actually leads to two-party domination in every country it's adopted in](http://rangevoting.org/TarrIrvSumm.html).

It's true that voting honestly for a *fringe* candidate (Yellow) is safe, since they'll be eliminated immediately and your second choice will go to a mainstream candidate (Green).  So IRV is better than plurality in this case (where Red would win even though a majority opposes Red):

[image: Fringe Yellow candidate does not spoil the election for Green]

However, when the third party candidate becomes more competitive (which is the whole point of adopting an alternative voting system), voting honestly for them takes away votes from your second choice, who will get eliminated first, and then your most-disliked candidate will win in the following round.  If the third party hadn't run, your more-preferred candidate would have won, so the third party is acting as a spoiler, and in fact the effect is *worse* than in plurality (red bar extends further to the right):

[image: Yellow moves closer to Green and splits the vote, allowing Red to win]

(These images are from [Voteline](http://zesty.ca/voting/voteline/))

Video illustration of this effect:

[[image: Video thumbnail Favorite Betrayal in Plurality and Instant Runoff Voting]

Favorite Betrayal in Plurality and Instant Runoff Voting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtKAScORevQ)

Primer also has a great video showing this effect:

[image: Video thumbnail]
[Simulating alternate voting systems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhO6jfHPFQU)

These effects have been modeled graphically on [1-dimensional](http://zesty.ca/voting/voteline/) and [2-dimensional](http://zesty.ca/voting/sim/) [political spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_spectrum#Other_multi-axis_models), and produce bizarre win regions where the population moving *toward* a candidate causes them to lose, and vice versa.  In this example, if the population's opinions shifted to the right, reducing support for Red and increasing support for Yellow, it would cause Red to win instead of Green!:

[image: Yellow is slightly farther from Green, causing the win regions to become non-monotonic]

In 2 dimensions, we can see IRV giving the election to Green even when the population is centered exactly on the Yellow candidate.  There's also a bizarre Yellow island that's nowhere near the Yellow candidate, and not present in any of the other voting systems pictured.

[image: Hare (IRV) creates non-monotonic win regions in 2D political space]

Approval voting or Condorcet ranking both have results that make sense, with the candidate nearest to the population center winning:

[image: Condorcet or Approval voting produces nearest-neighbor win regions]

Animated 2D comparison of different systems:

[[image: Video thumbnail]

Yee Animations 0.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPMks6afuM8)

### IRV excludes moderates

Similar to above, if there are two more-extreme partisan candidates and a moderate/compromise candidate in the middle, the compromise candidate is eliminated early (for not being anyone's first choice), even though they are the best representative of the population as a whole, and a more partisan candidate is elected instead.  This is called the "[center-squeeze effect](https://electology.org/center-squeeze-effect)".

This is essentially what happened in [Burlington Vermont's 2009 election](https://bolson.org/%7Ebolson/2009/20090303_burlington_vt_mayor.html), which led to [IRV being repealed](https://electology.org/irv-repealed).  Montroll was in the center relative to the other major candidates, but was eliminated in the 4th round, and [a more extreme candidate won](http://wiki.electorama.com/wiki/2009_Burlington,_Vermont_Mayoral_Election), even though Montroll had a higher approval rating than the winner.

Here are the ideal win regions for 14 candidates, with each winning if the population center is nearest to them:

[image: Voronoi diagram of 14-candidate election]

[Here's what happens in IRV](http://rangevoting.org/IrvExtreme.html).  All the candidates near the center are eliminated, and only the more extreme fringe candidates can win:

[image: Diagram of win regions of IRV 14-candidate election]

You can also see the center-squeeze effect by measuring the probability distribution of winners along a political spectrum as [this 2024 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.09734) did, showing that RCV has a moderating effect compared to FPTP, excluding extremist candidates from winning:

[image: Tomlinson 2024 Figure 3, showing the winner distributions of Plurality vs IRV]

However, if you [extend this same metric to include other voting systems](https://github.com/endolith/elsim/tree/master/examples#figure-3--comparison-with-other-systems), you can see that almost every other system does a better job of electing the most representative candidate, and RCV actually still has a pretty bad center-squeeze effect, with that same divot in the middle:

[image: Extension of Tomlinson's graphs to also include Two-Round System/Contingent Vote, Approval Voting, STAR Voting, Borda Count, Coombs method, and Condorcet]

This effect [gets worse the more candidates there are on the ballot, and the more representative they are](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2110786). More choices and better candidates on the ballot?  Under IRV ("Hare"), this leads to worse results:

[image: Merrill 1984 Fig 4b "Social Utility Efficiency under Spatial-Model Assumptions" (201 voters, two dimensions, correlation = .5, relative dispersion = .5) showing Hare performance dropping off as number of candidates increases]

These two effects lead to political polarization and two-party domination.  You can see how IRV skews Australia's House in favor of the two main parties even though 1/4 to 1/3 of the population would prefer third parties (while [STV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote) leads to a more proportional Senate):

[image: Bar graph of primary votes vs seats in Australia's House (IRV) and Senate (STV)]

### IRV is not a Condorcet system

In [the Burlington election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burlington_mayoral_election,_2009), Montroll was also the [Condorcet winner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_criterion), meaning he would have won against every other candidate in head-to-head elections.  The overall preferences of the population were unambiguous:

- Montroll > Kiss > Wright > Smith > Simpson

But IRV is not a Condorcet system; it eliminated Montroll and elected the population's second favorite Kiss instead.

Likewise, in the [2022 Alaska congressional special election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Alaska%27s_at-large_congressional_district_special_election#Results_2), [54% of voters preferred Begich over Peltola, and 61% of voters preferred Begich over Palin](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/75325/10373), with an unambiguous Condorcet order of

- Begich > Peltola > Palin

Yet because Hare RCV only counts first-choice votes in each round, and Palin and Begich split the Republican vote between them, Begich was eliminated before the others.  If Palin had strategically dropped out before the general election, Begich (also Republican) would have won the election, but she acted as a spoiler, causing the Democrat Peltola to win.

If your system doesn't elect the most-*liked* candidate (the "Utilitarian Winner"), it should at least elect the most-*preferred* candidate (the "Condorcet Winner").  IRV guarantees neither.

Some argue that although it doesn't *guarantee* a Condorcet winner, [it is still *likely* to elect one](https://fairvote.org/every_rcv_election_in_the_bay_area_so_far_has_produced_condorcet_winners/).  This may be true in a two-party system with only one or two strong candidates, but in an election with multiple similar candidates, [simulations show it to not perform particularly well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_efficiency):

[image: Merrill 1984 Fig2d Condorcet Efficiency under Spatial-Model Assumptions (relative dispersion = 0.5)]

(Performance is similar when [measuring the likelihood of electing the "most-liked" candidate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_utility_efficiency).)

### IRV enables tyranny of the majority

Here's a (contrived) example:

- Candidate A is loved by 55% of the population, and hated by 45% of the population (55% overall approval rating)
- Candidate B is liked by everyone (85% overall approval rating)

Under IRV, the polarizing Candidate A would win, because they are preferred by a majority, even though the population as a whole would be much happier with Candidate B winning the election.

"Utilitarian" or "consensus" voting systems like Score/Approval [choose the candidate with the higher approval rating, which is considered a better outcome by advocates of these systems](http://leastevil.blogspot.com/2012/03/tyranny-of-majority-weak-preferences.html).

Another way of viewing this is that Candidate A is a great representative of *half* of the population, while Candidate B is a good representative of the *entire* population.

Majoritarian voting systems are not as inclusive, leading to adversarial politics, inefficiency, and even [civil wars](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f929/aff03361240d390029a5d7f66ded25d2eac2.pdf).

### 2016 election

> And if the Republican primaries had used ranked-choice voting, Trump wouldn't have won the nomination, since a majority of the electorate was against him, it's just that the anti-Trump vote was split.

There's not much good data about this, but it's likely that IRV would still have elected Trump:

- ["probably really Trump would have been the IRV victor."](http://rangevoting.org/Trump2015.html)
- ["it's apparent that under ranked voting, Trump would have won with a majority of the votes"](http://riderrants.blogspot.com/2016/11/the-lefts-post-election-whining-about.html)

Score or Condorcet voting would likely have elected Sanders or Kasich, as they had the highest approval ratings:

- ["Sanders turned out to be the most honestly preferred candidate." .. "We might look at Sanders’ win here as being a “true” Condorcet winner."](https://electology.org/blog/honest-voters-had-preference-2016)
- ["Score Voting (all primary contenders, all parties): Either Sanders or Kasich would have won."](http://rangevoting.org/USA2016retro.html#concl)
- ["Notice that even though Democrats voted for Clinton, it was Sanders who really was liked by the most Americans.  If we didn’t have separate primaries, Sanders could have won."](https://halfout.wordpress.com/2016/08/13/voting-needs-to-change-americans-liked-sanders-and-kasich-better-than-clinton-and-trump/)
- ["America really chose Sanders and Kasich."](https://www.reddit.com/r/EndFPTP/comments/4vcq9r/evidence_that_voting_needs_to_change_the_nominees/)

Comment: I actually like the "tyranny of the majority" feature you mentioned at the end.  Are there voting systems that keep the tyranny of the majority in place but fix the rest of the flaws of IRV you mentioned?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Why do you like it?

Comment: Well, I think the point of elections is majority rule, and then you should use other mechanisms like checks and balances and the like to deal with the fact that there's a minority who doesn't agree with the majority.  In any case, do you know of any voting system that improves on IRV in other ways but still makes A win over B in the example you gave at the end?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I'm just curious how you came to that conclusion. Isn't the purpose of elections to choose the candidate who best embodies the will of the people?  Anyway, [Condorcet systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_method) are also majoritarian, so you might like those. [Schulze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulze_method) is the only one I've seen talked about, so I assume it's superior to the others in some way, though I don't know the details.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan [Score Runoff Voting](http://www.equal.vote/) uses Score for the first round, to choose the two candidates with highest approval ratings (replacing party primaries), then faces them off in an instant runoff where one will get a majority of the votes.  So it's majoritarian in a sense, but only after eliminating the extremely polarizing candidates first. Simulations say it resists strategic voting better than pure Score, as well.

Comment: Is that 'excludes moderates' true of all forms of IRV (or is there only one form?) My understanding of IRV was that it excludes the fringes more so than the moderates. It gives fringes a chance, but allows the moderate fall-back. But maybe I'm thinking of ranked choice?

Comment: @blip There are many ranked-choice systems, but the phrase "ranked choice voting" is typically used to mean this system in particular, at least in the US.  I guess taken literally, there are other voting systems that use "instant runoff" rounds, too, but likewise the term "IRV" almost only refers to this system.  I'll edit to be more specific.  Center squeeze does not happen in all ranked systems.  Condorcet ranked systems like Schulze would have elected Montroll, for instance.

Comment: @blip Center squeeze also doesn't happen in rated systems like Score or Approval (which I think I prefer over ranked)

Comment: Where did you get (or how did you make) these figures? I love them.

Comment: @indigochild There are links in the text, but I'll repeat them: http://zesty.ca/voting/voteline/ (click "Help") http://zesty.ca/voting/sim/ http://bolson.org/voting/sim_one_seat/www/spacegraph.html http://rangevoting.org/IEVS/Pictures.html

Comment: @CraigHicks The bell curves are 1-dimensional, and fit the actual data just fine.  See [2014 Political Polarization in the American Public](http://www.people-press.org/2014/06/12/section-1-growing-ideological-consistency/pp-2014-06-12-polarization-1-04/) for graphs.  Anyway, if you go to [voteline](http://zesty.ca/voting/voteline/), and then double-click on the bell curve, it will switch to bimodal or uniform distributions, but it doesn't matter; they still have the same problems.  Why would IRV get more voters to the polls?

Comment: @endolith - Thanks for your comment. I've deleted my previous comment feeling I ought to  look into the data more first.  IRV has the capacity to field more candidates.  If you consider the multidimensional space of  election issues and the voters distributed as points in that space, then with more candidates it will be possible to have a lower sum of distances between each voter and their closest  candidate, compared to if there were only two candidates.

Comment: @CraigHicks I think people usually talk about the centroid of voters, not the minimized sum of distances (geometric median), since a single voter moving around can move the median around a lot

Comment: @endolith - I was actually talking about a hypothetical issue space, whereas I think you are talking about a candidate space - but it doesn't matter let me restate my hypothesis:
// Hypothesis 1 -  Voters are more like to get up and vote if they feel great affinity for at least one candidate, than if they feel only neutral or unhappy about all candidates, even if they are more unhappy with some candidates than others.  // Hypothesis 2 - An IRV general election would produce candidates aiming for each niche set of #1 votes.  // Lemma 1 - given Hyp 1 and Hyp 2, the turnout would be large.

Comment: @endolith - (cont.)  Of course, if the niche voters only vote for their #1 niche candidate and specify no other rankings, the IRV would not work as intended.  Although the resulting ballot information might be useful for forming practical and popular platforms for future elections.

Comment: @CraigHicks The voters are plotted in issue space, and the centroid of voters is compared with candidate positions in the same space. That's where the 2D diagrams come from. I think I agree with your argument (though if people turn out to vote honestly for niche candidates, IRV's flaws will not make them happy).

Comment: @endolith - Re Burlington, can we be certain that if Montroll had won, the IRV system still wouldn't have been repealed?  The second and third place losers might both have been upset, and convinced that there candidate should have won.

Comment: @CraigHicks No, we can't be certain, but they didn't repeal it after the first election.

Comment: endolith @blip
This is a real example of IRV "working" - 
http://www.nytimes.com/2010/11/12/us/politics/12bcvoting.html
. A know it can fail for the "center" (see my self-deleted answer below), but to say it always or usually fails might not be correct.

Comment: @CraigHicks IRV doesn't "always or usually" fail, but it fails more often than most other proposed systems.  Simulations show that many other systems perform better than IRV ([VSE](http://electology.github.io/vse-sim/VSEbasic/), [BR](https://electology.org/tactical-voting-basics)) and that IRV's non-monotonicity happens unacceptably often: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonicity_criterion#Estimated_likelihood_of_IRV_lacking_monotonicity)

Comment: @endolith - I am certainly open to the idea of other voting systems.  However, sometimes the evaluations in the literature are weak.  E.g., in the example you cited "Instant-runoff voting and the two-round system are not monotonic", it shows two true right-left voters conspiring to vote false left-right in order to get center elected instead of left.  Which implies that their true second choice was center, not left.  Hence, a contradiction in what their true choice was.  And and if right-center was really their true vote, they could have voted that way and center would have been elected.

Comment: @CraigHicks I agree it's poorly worded. Think of it this way:  If those two voters' preference is L>R>C, and they vote honestly, their least favorite wins.  If they dishonestly *decrease* support for their favorite, and vote R>L>C, then their favorite wins. No sane voting system should behave in this way. Decreasing support for a candidate should not cause them to win, nor vice versa.

Comment: @endolith - "... But if at least two of the five voters who ranked Right first, and Left second, would raise Left, and vote 1st Left, 2nd Right; then Left would be defeated by these votes in favor of Center. ... "  I'm looking, but I don't see what you are saying ("... If those two voters' preference is L>R>C, and they vote honestly, their least favorite win...") as being the scenario depicted.

Comment: @endolith - Nevertheless, in IRV, it is easy to see that many may be left wishing they had voted differently because then a different preferable (to them) outcome would have been achieved.  I do understand that shortcoming, and that other methods try to address that.  
At the same time, it is interesting to note that many object to what they consider a system that elects compromise candidates.  What kind of election is needed to select the criterion?

Comment: @Craig The first scenario in WP is my "dishonest" case (R>L>C causes L to win), and the 2nd scenario is my "honest" case (L>R>C causes C to win). I'm interpreting it backwards from the description. You're right that the "raise Left" text doesn't make any real-world sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55495/discussion-between-endolith-and-craig-hicks).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Can you ask your majority rule question as a separate question and we can delete the conversation here?

Comment: @CraigHicks Do you think we could turn the discussion about "contradiction in what their true choice was" into a separate question (even if we've already answered it), so it can be deleted from here?

Comment: @endolith Do any of the IRV methods for a single office (not a legislature) start the elimination process by getting rid of the person with the most lowest rankings? And perhaps alternate after than between the the most lowest ranks and the least highest ranks? I'm curious as to how that would effect the outcome.

Comment: @Readin That's [Coomb's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coombs%27_method), which works better than IRV in some senses.

Comment: hay, @endolith .  i see another contribution from you about a topic close to my heart.

Comment: Wrong Conclusion in Tyranny of majority example : You say that A is Loved by 55, hated by 45, but B is liked by 85 . So you conclude that A will be voted, while B would be the better choice.        You call this a flaw of IRV, but the same things will happen in current majority system too

Comment: @NickAsher First, yes, it's a flaw of FPTP, Runoff voting, RCV, Condorcet systems, STAR, etc. But systems like Score and Approval would choose the broadly-liked candidate. Second, I actually said that B is liked (but not loved) by *everyone*. The "not loved" is why the favorability is less than 100%

Comment: I question the statement that IRV "leads to" two party domination.  At most it could be said that it fails to eliminate it.  The example which purports to show how voting for a third party can cause all your choices to be eliminated it theoretically possible but unlikely.  If Green and Yellow voters really don't want Red in power each one will put the other non-Red party as their second choice.  If Green is eliminated surprisingly then most of their votes will go to Yellow and Yellow will win not Red.  If polling ever shows this is likely expect Green to make "give Yellow your 2nd" a policy.

Comment: @EricNolan Well it leads to two-party domination just as much as FPTP does. There are FPTP countries with multiple strong parties, etc. Half of Green voters *did* put Red as their last choice, and 100% of Yellow voters did.  You're ignoring that half of Green voters prefer Red as their second choice.  Everyone who advocates IRV talks about one specific contrived two-party scenario and says "See, it eliminates the spoiler effect!" while ignoring the much more common scenarios like the one I've shown.

Comment: @EricNolan In other words, the colors aren't parties, they're voters.  Right-wing Green fans can tell Left-wing Green fans to "give Yellow your 2nd" all they want, but that's not going to happen because it's not what Left-wing Greens want.

Comment: @endolith, i wanna point you to [my recent paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14assN41UL7Mib9PpwsjM63ZT17k9admC/view) and to this [2004 Scientific American article](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m6qn6Y7PAQldKNeIH2Tal6AizF7XY2U4/view) coauthored by Nobel laureate Eric Maskin (and FairVote dishonestly counts Maskin as a supporter of their IRV version of RCV).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson The first paragraph sounds like you're advocating Score-based systems :)

Comment: @endolith Regarding the related question: [What are the pros and cons of ranked-choice voting compared to first-past-the-post voting?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/86489/28554): I have just awarded the first bounty in a series of a few bounties. I posted the second bounty. I value your answer above. I also encourage you to convert your comment about the Nazi Germany on item 8 of my question  into an answer. The comment was probably deleted by mistake by the moderators (not intended). I will be happy to consider your answer, no matter how brief, for the bounty! TYIA.

Answer (score 16):

#### Trump

> And if the Republican primaries had used ranked-choice voting, Trump wouldn't have won the nomination, since a majority of the electorate was against him, it's just that the anti-Trump vote was split.

Maybe.  However, by the end of the primaries, Donald Trump was winning an absolute majority of the vote.  Instant Runoff Voting (IRV) or plurality, an absolute majority is a winner.  It's possible that ranked choice would have helped in the early primaries (and Trump would have never achieved the inevitability at the end), but it's by no means guaranteed.

If your goal is getting rid of Trump, then I would suggest getting rid of partisan primaries instead.  That could have led to a candidate like John Kasich or Jim Webb winning.

IRV might have helped in the general election.  Presumably Jill Stein voters preferred Gary Johnson and Hillary Clinton to Trump.  And Clinton voters probably preferred Johnson and Stein to Trump.  It's not clear how Johnson voters felt though.  Libertarians have traditionally been split on second choice candidates.  In any case, IRV is heavily dominated by the first choice.  Since Trump and Clinton were the overwhelming first choices, it would have still been mainly between them.

#### Ranked choice in general

1. Ranked choice ballots are more complicated to fill out.  Instead of filling out a single choice, voters have to fill out a list.
2. Ranked choice voting is harder to understand.  It's not as obvious why one candidate wins over another.
3. Ranked choice is harder to process.  Instead of just counting votes, the system has to count ordered lists.
4. Ranked choice doesn't fix problems with partisanship or oppression of minority groups in favor of majority opinion.  But those are common complaints about the current system.

Note that these aren't insurmountable details.  In particular, computers make the implementation difficulties much less important.  But they are problems with every [ranked choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_voting_system) method.

Also note that this doesn't include any of the arguments *for* ranked choice voting methods.  This question only asks for arguments *against*.  Balancing the competing arguments would be more opinion-based.

#### IRV in particular

Plurality is better than IRV by some criteria.  In particular, [monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonicity_criterion), [consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_criterion), and [participation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participation_criterion).  Quick summary, there are tactical reasons to list different orders than one's actual preference.

IRV does not meet the [Condorcet criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_criterion).  So in a high partisan environment, it tends to devolve into the same choices as plurality voting.

Of course, IRV is also better than plurality voting on some criteria.  In fact, every [voting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_system) has some criterion on which another voting system is superior.  In particular, the Condorcet criterion and [Later No Harm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Later-no-harm_criterion) are incompatible, so no voting system fulfills both.

Comment: Regarding using the 2016 Republican primaries as an example: 1. One of the biggest advantages of ranked voting is that tactical voting is far less necessary, so you can not just take results of a majority vote and assume people would have had the same 1st preferences if it had been a ranked vote. And 2., with ranked voting, primaries are no longer necessary, because a party has no disadvantage anymore by running multiple candidates. But the rest of this answer is a really good synopsis.

Comment: @Philipp IRV/"RCV" does not have those benefits, though. It still has vote splitting and spoiler effects which require tactical voting.

Comment: While I like the 'Trump' part of the first, it's likely much fairer to say "fewer fringe candidates winning". IRV ultimately (in theory, at least) leads to a more centrist result as the 'less extreme option' tends to be shared by more people that the extreme options.

Comment: Hmm...I need an analogy here. Without IRV, you could end up with pepperoni and licorice flavored ice cream for dessert. With IRV, you might end up with French Vanilla. Not everyone would choose French Vanilla if they only had one vote, but most people would agree French Vanilla is an OK compromise. :)

Comment: @Brythan I think you make a lot of good realistic informative points, but the speculation of results of the last election if they had been held under IRV are not so useful - e.g., Bernie and others would probably have been candidates under IRV so your starting hypothesis about the candidates present is already wrong.

Comment: @blip IRV would choose Pepperoni or Licorice.  It excludes compromise candidates.  Score voting would choose French Vanilla.

Comment: Bernie would have won under an approval vote

Comment: "However, by the end of the primaries, Donald Trump was winning an absolute majority of the vote." Wasn't this largely due to the fact that he was the only candidate left in the race for the last 2 months? Before the April 26 primaries, Trump had achieved an absolute majority in only a single state (his then-home state of New York) and one territory (N. Mariana Islands.)

Comment: "Libertarians have traditionally been split on second choice candidates."  No not really, the Libertarian party typically tends to spoil for Republicans and there is a strong Libertarian wing of the Republican Party.  They certainly would have elected Hilary in 2016 as Libertarians tend to be opposed to big government in general, and Hilary was the "Big Government Candidate" of that election cycle, so it's not likely she would have been picked as a second choice.

Answer (score 3):

Ranked choice voting would increase the amount of time it takes to determine the winner of elections.

Elections in the US are already painfully slow - the very act of taking weeks to determine a winner in some races has contributed to the crisis in confidence of democracy among some fraction of republican voters.

By switching to a more complicated system, election results could be even further delayed.  This would cause more people to think the results were rigged.  These would be undesirable effects.

Comment: Ranked choice does not have to increase how long election results take and most of the delays with results are caused by restrictions put in place around counting mail in votes before election day and other restrictions. Also as there is a long delay between the election and taking office there is no need to have same day results.

Comment: Actually, you do need same day results, like any other functioning democracy to install confidence in elections.  In practice, ranked choice *does* increase the time taken to determine a winner, like Alaska senate 2022 or NYC mayor 2021.

Comment: No you don't, there is no reason to have same day voting results and forcing that to happen causes more people to be excluded. When you have states that make it illegal to count and mail in or early ballots until after the polls close on election day it becomes an impossible goal. Not to mention we have never had the official results on election day and never will do the the short amount of time between polls closing and the end of the day. What people need are accurate results not speedy results. Remember the fact that we never get final results on election day just predictions.

Answer (score 2):

A. Big part of an election IS to show a mandate for the winner. To show a mandate, you need to have popularity. Or "absolute preference" for a candidate - " I like candidate XYZ too win".

Ranked voting shows only "relative preference" - "I like candidate XYZ more than ABC" but it could very well be that I dislike both.

Thus a winner of a ranked voting cannot assure the voters that he or she has the mandate to govern.

Edit: another way to look at this, the winner of a rank voting system is the least disliked candidate, while a regular voting produces the most popular winner.

Comment: suppose 3 cands a, b, c with ranked voting: //
a > c > b = 50% //
b > c > a = 50% //
c > * > * = 0% //
Cand "c" the extreme case of the least disliked but never most popular candidate.  But c will be eliminated in the first round and it will be a toss up between a and b.  //  On each round IRV eliminates the candidate with least #1 votes in that round - that gives an intuitive explanation of why c, the compromise candidate, could not win.

Comment: i can make the example simpler for you. Say you have two candidates and two voting systems, one is popular vote and another is rank vote. Candidate A is declared a winder in a popular vote. you can infer from that, correctly, that Candidate A has the most support thus the mandate;

Comment: I can give an example where "mandate" becomes questionable in your scenario.
Two candidates, A and B, are the only ones running in the election.  A has 25% support, B has 25% support, but 50% are completely dissatisfied with both candidates and do not vote.  Either A or B will get elected, but 75% of the electorate are completely dissatisfied with either.  
Is that a "mandate"?

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with ranked choice is that it not show how much do you like or rate someone.

If some brothers are voting between an spider and a dog to be their pet, if an the arachnophonic kid vote "dog is better than spider", it will have the same meaning than a kid that likes both (but prefer dog) and vote "dog is better than spider".

Comment: This is more of a comment than a real answer.

Comment: Is there any system that *does* do this? In such a system, wouldn't the dog-preferer just *pretend* to be arachnophobic so their vote counts for more?

Answer (score 0):

Any election system is unfair if it has single-member districts. Fair representation can only be achieved with multiple-member districts.

Of course, executive governments are usually single-member. But parliamentary / congress systems with single-member districts can be easily abolished.

Comment: Can you make this more of an answer to this specific question?  IRV is a single-winner election method, but it's used in multi-winner constituencies like Australia's House, which is a valid criticism.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is directed at instant runoff voting vis-a-vis multiple round voting, such as systems where a majority of the vote is required to win the final round.

The big virtue of multiple round voting is that it is easier for many voters, in terms of both time expended for candidate research, and conceptual difficulty, to make a first choice pick only, than it is to rank other contenders in a race beyond the first choice candidate.

In a multiple round voting system, if your first choice candidate doesn't win in the first round, you have additional time to research the candidates who remain, knowing that the research is directly relevant to the outcome, without having to have spent a lot of useless time researching second and third priorities in races where it will never come to an "instant runoff" because first choice decisions will end up resolving the race, or where a voter's first choice makes it into the next round.

Thus, the decision on second choice candidates in a second round is likely to be better informed and hence higher in quality, than in an instant runoff voting conceptual "second round".

The downside of having multiple rounds is that often this is framed as a "top two candidates in the first round" make the second round, and when this happens, the candidates who make it into the second round may not accurately reflect the second choices of the voters whose first choice candidates are eliminated.

Answer (score -1):

With situations you outlined, there are some bad assumptions you're making.  First, in the scenario where A gets 40% of the vote and B and C get 30% of the vote apiece, you assert that 60% of the population does not approve of candidate A, despite his win.  You get this number by adding B and C together.  However, this does not mean that B and C attract equal opposition to A.  Rather, it means that 60% of the electorate opposes A, but 70% opposes B and 70% opposes C.  A first past the post system does not mean that the candidate is disliked by the electorate if he doesn't receive a vote, but rather he was not the first pick.  C supporters may lean more towards A, but see C as the better candidate.  However, if C dropped out, they still like A more than B.  These metrics can't be accounted in a first pass the post system, which does not care about the votes not received, so long as the winner receive the most.

This is true with the assertion that Donald Trump would not win.  All we know is that the support of the less successful candidates meant that Donald Trump was not their first pick, as opposed to #NeverTrump.  You can only assume that Trump will get a portion of the support of people who still liked him over other candidates.

If we look at the original set up of a 40%/30%/30% split, Candidate A is still likely to win in a First Pass the Post because he only needs to secure 36% of C's support (11% of the total available voters) to win.  Where as B would need to secure 70% of C's support (21% of the total available voters).  Keep in mind that C's support does not mean disapproval of A or B.  It could be B < A < C or A< B < C.  In our real world model, You assume that Kasich Supporters would support Cruise before Trump, without taking into account that Kasiche supporters might have stronger feelings of opposition to Cruise than Trump.

So that's just with some math of yours not with your system.

With your system, lets add to the mix of canadates A, B, C the new comers D, and E.  If I arrange my ballot so that C < B < A and never rate D and E because I cannot stand either of them (effectively never voting for them), what happens to my vote if A, B, and C are eliminated?  Here my vote is never given to a any candidate because I did not choose either.  To correct would you require to rate D and E?  If so, what if I use my freedom of speech to still choose not to rate D and E and my ballot is thrown out because it is not complete?  What if I do cast a vote for a winning candidate in my order, and still refuse to vote D or E... does that discount my vote?

Comment: You have a good and overlooked point here. Taking the 2016 election, and assuming that ranked voting replaced the primary, we would have 5 Democrats (not Sanders), 3 third party (Sanders, Johnson, Stein) and 17 Republicans. The GOP will win this election just by exhausting the field, assuming that no Democrats rank any Republicans. Also, the winner will not be Trump, Bush, Cruz or any top candidate, because those were all eliminated in early rounds. It will be somebody far down the list, like Santorum or Jindal, and the more Rs the Ds rank, the farther down the list of candidates we go.

Comment: Could that be solved with a weighted choice? One has 100 points, to distribute between the candidates (instead of just ranking them), in the case you described D and E would get zero points. The vote would still be correct.

Comment: @WoJ:  On it's face, I would say no...  the first, second, third... ect choice is weighted in that your vote will only move if your first choice is the runner up, you don't get your vote changed, but if your first choice is eliminated, it will go to the next favorite that has not yet been eliminated.  It solves the issue of third parties spoiling as those parties saw high numbers in 2016 because the two major parties were both considered terrible candidates.

Answer (score -8):

A prime argument against ranked choice voting is - there's nothing particularly wrong with the current voting system. Why change? What could that change bring that we don't have today?

Yes, we had a dismal 2016 presidential election, with two decidedly flawed candidates. Even the third party candidate sucked that year. The 2016 US election was a perfect storm of lousy choices.

That isn't the fault of the voting system. It's the fault of the parties for letting the situation devolve, and the fault of the voters for not demanding better.

Doesn't matter what voting system you have. As long as you have an electorate who is so easily distracted by smokescreens and irrelevant platforms, and doesn't focus on what is important for the future of the nation, you'll get poor results.

Comment: There's plenty wrong with FPP, the inability for a third-party candidate to get traction is the most obvious one.