# How did Alaska "change its primary system recently" and was it "to dilute the possibility of a conservative or Trump-inspired challenger"?

Tags: united-states, election, voting-systems, primaries, alaska

Politico's [GOP pushes Murkowski to stay in line against Biden’s Covid bill](https://www.politico.com/news/2021/03/04/gop-murkowski-biden-covid-bill-473665) includes the following:

> Murkowski is unique, however, and so is her home of Alaska. The state is suffering economically, the pandemic has exacerbated the state’s woes, and she's complained repeatedly that Biden’s less fossil fuel-friendly energy policies are hurting Alaskans. **Moreover, her state changed its primary system recently to dilute the possibility of a conservative or Trump-inspired challenger, giving her room to legislate from the middle.**

**Questions:**

1. How did Alaska "...chang(e) its primary system recently..."
2. Was it really specifically to "...dilute the possibility of a conservative or Trump-inspired challenger..."? Was that the main reason that the change was made?

Comment: There's already a [`democratic-primary`](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/democratic-primary) tag with 39 questions, so I've added a `republican-primary` tag. The asymmetry is curious, so I've asked [Why is there a democratic-primary tag with 39 questions but until just now no republican-primary tag?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4738/16047)

Comment: oops, now tagging is back to `D:39, R:0` :-)

Comment: all but 4 questions with that tag were 2018 or later, and there hasn't been a real GOP primary in that time frame

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[Alaska Ballot Measure 2 made two big changes to elections](https://www.alaskapublic.org/2021/03/04/as-alaska-prepares-for-first-ranked-choice-election-experts-say-now-is-the-time-to-educate-and-test/), both of which are expected to reduce the power of the main parties:

1. Party-run primary elections are replaced with non-partisan primary elections (sometimes called Jungle primaries). In a non-partisan primary, all candidates, regardless of party, run against each other in  a primary election and the top vote-getters move on to the general election. Usually, in a non-partisan primary, the top-two candidates move on, but in Alaska's new system the top **four** move forward. This is because of the second change instituted by Ballot Measure 2:
2. The normal first-past-the-post system has been replaced with ranked choice voting among the top-4 candidates from the primary. Instead of casting a single vote for a candidate, voters rank their candidates. If no one receives a majority of the votes, the last place candidate is removed and their voters are assigned to the other candidates based on their second choices. This continues until one candidate has a majority.

---

The main advantage for Senator Murkowski is the elimination of the closed party primary. Murkowski's image as a moderate has made here popular with the state at large, but earned her enemies among the core of the Republican party. In a closed primary, she would have to win a majority of votes from the most committed Republican party members, where her moderate record would be a detriment.

This isn't just theoretical: in 2010 [she lost the Republican primary to a candidate backed by Sarah Palin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisa_Murkowski#2010), before running anyway and winning election as a write in candidate. A non-partisan primary would let her qualify for the general election by appealing to *all* Alaskans, not just Republicans.

Ranked choice voting is (at least in theory) helpful to moderates. Even if a right-wing Republican made it through the primary, Murkowski, as the lesser of two evils, is likely to be the second choice of most Democrats and so she'd likely benefit from redistributed votes in the second or third round of the election.

Both of these changes mean that Murkowski has less need to toe the party line and can challenge Republican orthodoxy without worrying about being eliminated in a closed primary.

UPDATE as of March 17th, 2021: Indeed, the Alaska Republican Party has recently censured Senator Murkowski for voting to convict Trump at his second impeachment trial and [is seeking to block her from running as a Republican](https://apnews.com/article/donald-trump-alaska-anchorage-lisa-murkowski-elections-abbf5443c98c3b8df52973e79deb4b44):

> The Alaska Republican Party has censured U.S. Sen. Lisa Murkowski for voting to convict former President Donald Trump at his impeachment trial and now doesn’t want her to identify as a GOP candidate in next year’s election, a member of the party’s State Central Committee said Tuesday.

> “But it also directed the party officials to recruit an opponent in the election and to the extent legally permissible, prevent Lisa Murkowski from running as a Republican in any election,” he said.

Thanks to Ballot Measure 2, however, they have much less power to do so. While they could encourage another Republican to run against her, and might (I'm unsure about this) be able to force her to run as an Independent, they can't simply block her from the ballot as they did in 2010:

---

As for your second question, I don't know of any evidence that it was *deliberately* designed to protect Murkowski from a primary challenger. The ["Yes on 2 for Better Elections"](https://www.vox.com/2020/11/19/21537126/alaska-measure-2-ranked-choice-voting-results) campaign pushes the idea of "accountability" and makes a big deal about Alaska's independent streak:

> “This is a victory for all Alaskans regardless of their political leaning,” Shea Siegert, manager of the Yes on 2 for Better Elections campaign, said in a statement Wednesday. “We now have an electoral system that lives up to Alaska’s independent streak by saying ‘to hell with politics let’s do what is right for Alaska.’”

So I'd guess their intention was to weaken the parties *in general*, rather than to protect Senator Murkowski *specifically*.

I think that sentence is mainly a strangely worded way of saying that this is the expected effect of the change, not that the change was made deliberately to have that effect.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer! It sounds like Alaska's system is now more like how Stack Exchange  elects moderators?

Comment: Wait, does this mean that if party A lets four candidates run and party B lets 100 more or less equally good candidates run in the jungle primary, then we can expect the A candidates to have two-digit percentages and the B candidates way less, i.e., all four winners will be from party A?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I understand the system as: N candidates enter (parties cannot prevent anyone from running - they would just endorse few candidates), voters pick top 4, then voters (can) rank those top 4, with the last place being thrown out and his/her votes go towards voters' 2nd or 3rd choices until one candidate gets above 50% and wins. It seems a pretty good system to me - nobody would want to rank 10+ candidates. Yeah, in theory, 100 candidates of party B would end up with few votes each and fail to enter second round. But you know who the top candidates are, so it wouldn't happen.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120465/discussion-on-answer-by-divibisan-how-did-alaska-change-its-primary-system-rece).

Comment: Ironically, "ranked choice voting" tends to *perpetuate* a two-party system, and is biased *against* "the middle". https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/14850/10373

Comment: @endolith that's pretty interesting! I wonder if it can be expanded into a supplementary answer here, or a "Why did Alaska... which perpetuates a two-party system?" question can be composed somehow?

Comment: @endolith Very interesting analysis. The main driver for moderation here, I think, is the nonpartisan primary. I also thought that the ranked choice voting would help too, but maybe not. The key factor from Murkowski’s perspective, though, is that the party can no longer block her candidacy

Comment: @divibisan I don't think the party leadership ever intended to block her candidacy. Rather, a large enough faction of the party's voters preferred a more partisan candidate, while Alaskans at large preferred a more moderate one. I would disagree with jungle primaries being a driver for moderation, though. On the contrary, they set up a situation where, not only could candidates splitting votes cause a less-favored candidate to be nominated for a party, they could cause _none_ of the candidates from a party to reach the general... and this happens frequently in California's jungle primaries.

Comment: @divibisan For an example of the problems with jungle primaries, say you had one party who 60% of voters preferred which ran 5 candidates and another party which 40% of voters preferred which ran only 2 candidates. Suppose support for those candidates was split roughly evenly within each party. The 5 candidates from the party strongly preferred by the majority could end up with around 12% each vs. 20% each for the 2 from the less-favored party, resulting in only the 2 candidates disliked most by a strong majority of voters being in the general election.

Comment: The Alaskan system of advancing 4 candidates rather than only 2 should help with that problem to a significant degree, but the problem still exists.

Comment: @reirab the biggest problem with the Alaskan system is that they've used plurality voting for the primary instead of a ranked system like STV, so strategic voting will still remain important in the primary stage

Comment: @JonathanReez Both the FPTP primary and the RCV general are problems.  :/  Both systems are based on counting only first-preference votes, which results in unintuitive and undemocratic outcomes.

Comment: @endolith yeah, ideally they'd just do approval voting for both the primary and the general